# How to Replace Word in code with Typed in text?

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I'm in need of a code where people can type in a word that replaces a certain "key" word with whatever they typed in. For context, I have a website where I provide donacode (Episode app) templates for users to copy and paste and use. However, the code requires people to replace a certain word with their own word. Right now I've instructed people to copy/paste code into a document and use Ctrl+F to replace all. But I want them to be able to just type in their word on my website then click on a generate button, and then the words in my code get changed to whatever they type in.

EDIT: Forgive me in advance, I'm not an expert HTML/java coding, I don't know the correct vocab or specifications.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve. If you click this link and scroll down, there's an option to type in a "name" and when you click on the "generate" button, it changes every single "CHARACTER" in the code to the name you typed in. This is what I need.

https://www.episodelife.com/2022/03/motorbike-script-template-rural-road-scene.html

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element `<text>` is not a valid HTML5 markup element.

Comment: How are the keywords identified in the document?

Comment: Don't use line breaks for layout spacing. That's not their purpose. Use margin or padding via CSS.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking for here. What are "all key words"? Please revise to be more clear, citing _specific_ aspects of your document.

Comment: Note that I've replaced your `<text>` element with a valid `<span>` element to remove some distraction from this post.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to REPLACE the text in the full string.

Using event handlers are a better method then inline onclick.

For my answer, I also use CSS to uppercase the input.

I'm using textContent to get the text content of the string to be updated also I'm upper casing the value in the replace too so that its always uppercase, so the user doesn't need to do it themselves.

```js
const btnChange = document.querySelector(".btnChange");
const inp = document.querySelector("#inp");
const output = document.querySelector("#output");
const content = output.textContent;

btnChange.addEventListener("click",() => {
   output.textContent = content.replaceAll("CHARACTER",inp.value.toUpperCase())
});
```

```css
#inp{
text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inp">
<button id="btn" class="btnChange"> Change Character Name </button>
<div id="output">CHARACTER enters from left to screen center CHARACTER</div>
```